# Symfony FileType customize

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, twig

I'm trying to customize the rendering of the File Input in Symfony with twig.

plugins.krajee.com/file-basic-usage-demo

I follow the documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html

In my config.yml

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig'
```

I try all methode...

1) Custome inside the the view in my view.html.twig (this is a copy past of the existing bootstrap layout, I just add class="file")

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
  {% block _user_file_widget -%}
    {% if type is not defined or type not in ['file', 'hidden'] %}
      {%- set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim}) -%}
    {% endif %}
    {%- set type = type|default('text') -%}
    <input class="file" type="file" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{%- endblock _user_file_widget %}
```

And in my FileType

```
 $builder->add('imageFile', FileType::class, array(
        'required'      => false,
        'label'         =>false,
         'block_name'   => 'file',
        ));
```

That gives me an error

```
The merge filter only works with arrays or "Traversable", got "NULL" as first argument.
```

2) Create an external file

In Ressources/View/Form/fields.html.twig

```
{% block form_widget_simple -%}
    {% if type is not defined or type not in ['file', 'hidden'] %}
        {%- set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('') ~ ' form-control')|trim}) -%}
    {% endif %}
    {%- set type = type|default('text') -%}
    <input class="file" type="file" {{ block('widget_attributes') }} {% if value is not empty %}value="{{ value }}" {% endif %}/>
{%- endblock form_widget_simple %}
```

And in the view

```
{% form_theme form 'form/fields.html.twig' %}
```

But all fields are customized...

3) Add class in the rendering in the view

```
{{ form_widget(form.imageFile, {'attr': {'class': 'file', 'type': 'file'} }) }}
```

And for this 2 last methods I get this:

[image]

I am open to all solution !

Thank you for your help.

Comment: probably you need to create form extension

Comment: The last one should be working definitely. Is there any error output in JavaScript's console?

Comment: @Pete No, there is no error in my JavaScript's console :/

Answer (score 0):

I found it !

It's working as I want using kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput.

After installation, I add some assetic in my config.yml

```
kartik_js:
    inputs:
        - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/js/fileinput.js"
        - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/js/locales/fr.js"
        - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/themes/explorer/theme.js"

kartik_css:
    inputs:
        - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css"
        - "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput/themes/explorer/theme.css"
```

Then in the view I add the css and js

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
    {% stylesheets '@kartik_css' combine=true %}
    <link href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}


{% javascripts '@kartik_js' combine=true %}
    <script src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
{% endjavascripts %}
```

The form widget

```
{{ form_widget(form.imageFile)}}
```

And the Javascrip

```
$("#fos_user_profile_form_imageFile").fileinput({
    language: 'fr',
    showUpload: false,
    allowedFileExtensions: ['jpg', 'png', 'gif']
});
```

The Result !

[Is Amazing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUaOy.png)

I hope this will help some one :)

Have a good day !